# The fsck: error2 error occurred when running the image

Tags: linux, qemu, images

I'm using qemu to run an image. If the mirroring is successful, I then run on gem5.
The image I use is at this website.
http://dist.gem5.org/dist/v20-1/images/x86/ubuntu-18-04/boot-exit.img.gz

I use the command below.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 boot-exit.img  -m size=8192 -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

Really Thanks!!!

I was able to log into the system successfully. The username is gem5 and the password is 12345.

But the following problem occurs when starting. How should I remove it?

[image]